# How to retrieve data from a csv file only in java not using JDBC ,sql

Tags: java

I have a csv file , from that file i want to retrieve particular records using only java without using Jdbc and Sql

Comment: JDBC and SQL are for _database_ access. If you have a CSV _file_ then read that file and collect all the records you need. Besides that, please take a [tour] and espeically read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with **Apache Commons CSV**, is simple and easy.

[DOCS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html)

[DOWNLOAD](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi)

Answer (score 0):

First, use inputStream and BufferedReader:

```
InputStream is;
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
```

Next use a loop to reader the bufferedReader and save to Array. You will need to split your CSV with the split function. Use "," as your delimiter. However, you can also use "//" or "/" depending on your file.

```
while((reader.readLine()) != null) {

Sting line = "";
String Test [] = line.split(",");
```

And finally, print the Array:

```
System.out.Println(Test.ToString());
```